# Uploading a python-docx document to Azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, python-docx

I'm trying to upload a document I created with `python-docx` to an azure blob storage. Locally I can save the file and upload the file from my local disk to Azure with the `upload_blob()` method. However, I want to upload the file directly to an Azure Storage with an Azure Function, any ideas on how to upload from the `save()` method? The `save` method expects a *path_or_stream*

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import io

pptx_file = io.BytesIO()
document.save(pptx_file)
pptx_file.seek(0)
upload_blob(pptx_file)
```